# правильный mapping данных json ObjectMapper

Tags: objective-c, json, swift

https://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/newest.json

```
    class Loans: Mappable {
    var name: String?
    var sector: String?
    var loanammount: Int?

    required init?(_ map: Map){

    }
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        name <- map["name"]
        sector <- map["sector"]
        loanammount <- map["loan_ammount"]
    }
}

class Arrayz: Mappable {
    var loans: [Loans]?
    required init?(_ map: Map){

    }
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        loans <- map["loans"]
    }
}
```

ломаю голову не могу понять как правильно сделать маппинг

upd
запрос

```
class kivaAPImanager {

    static let sharedAPI = kivaAPImanager()
    var URL = "https://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/newest.json"

    func arrayWithDictRequest() -> Observable<[Arrayz]> {
        return Observable.create { observer in
            let request = Alamofire.request(.GET, self.URL).responseArray { (response: Response<[Arrayz], NSError>) in
                if let error = response.result.error {
                    observer.on(.Error(error))
                } else {
                    observer.on(.Next(response.result.value!))
                    observer.on(.Completed)
                }
            }

            return AnonymousDisposable {
                request.cancel()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

вывожу сюда

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!



    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    var values = Variable([Arrayz]())
    let indicator = ViewIndicator()
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        values.asObservable()
            .bindTo(tableView.rx_itemsWithCellIdentifier("Cell", cellType: TableViewCell.self)) {
                (row, element, cell) in

//                cell.nameLabel?.text = 
//                cell.nameLabel?.text = element.
//                cell.nameLabel?.text =  != nil ? element.name! : "noName"
//                cell.loanLabel?.text = element.loanammount != nil ? String(element.loanammount!) : "0"
//                cell.sectorLabel?.text = element.sector != nil ? element.sector! : "noSector"

            }
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)


        kivaAPImanager.sharedAPI.arrayWithDictRequest()
            .subscribeNext { response in
                self.values.value = response
            }
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

            print(values)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: мэппинг чего куда и зачем?

Comment: все еще не понятно. ну получили вы json. что вы с ним дальше хотите сделать?

Comment: все я уже понял в чем проблема я пытался распарсить массив а у меня   приходил обьект

Answer (score 1, accepted):

переписал запрос и все получилось (пытался получить массив, хотя нужно было объект)

```
class kivaAPImanager {

static let shareAPI = kivaAPImanager()
var URL = "https://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/newest.json"

func requestArray() -> Observable<NewestResponse> {
    return Observable.create { observer in
        let request = Alamofire.request(.GET, self.URL).responseObject { (response: Response<NewestResponse, NSError>) in
            if let error = response.result.error {
                observer.on(.Error(error))
            } else {
                observer.on(.Next(response.result.value!))
                observer.on(.Completed)
            }
        }

        return AnonymousDisposable {
            request.cancel()
        }
    }
}
}
```